# PowerShell RegEx trying to output number after matching a string

Tags: regex, powershell

Here is my code:

```
    $input_path = 'C:\powershell\capture.txt'
    $output_file = 'C:\powershell\raw.txt'
    $regex = "/(closed,\s\d+[.,\d.*]{0,})/"
    select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

What i am trying to do is output the total rows after "closed, " i have the above regex which works because i tested this on regex101.com but the output file contains nothing. Here is the document that i am trying to extract from:

```
      [INFO] Agent 'Agent1' - started
      [INFO] TextDatasource 'Datasource1' - opened
      [INFO] TextDatasource 'Datasource1' - file opened: D:\python\domain_com.csv
      [INFO] Get URL: http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_recsite_front&Itemid=75
      [INFO] Init State - get URL: http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_recsite_front&Itemid=75
      [INFO] Page1 - next page element is not found for pattern: 'Page Pattern2'
      [INFO] TextDatasource 'Datasource1' - closed, 10,000 rows are stored
      [INFO] Agent 'Agent1' - stopped
```

So the output text file would contain: 10,000

And also store 10,000 in a variable for later use.. i.e. $rowcount =

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go:

```
$rowcount=Select-String -Path .\in.txt -Pattern "closed,\s([\d,\.]+)" -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Groups[1].value}
echo $rowcount > $output_file
```

just FYI: you don't need / in your regex